# Event end date modify using hook

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook, event-calendar

I am using [The event calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/).
I would like to adjust the events. so they don't move over to **past events** for an **hour after they end**. So for example, if an event ends at 3 PM EST we don't want it to move to the past events page until 4 PM EST.

**In short:** I want to set the event end date before 1 hour.

So Evet not going on past.

I have added the below code on the functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'posts_filter2',15 );

function posts_filter2( $query ){
   $type = 'tribe_events';
   if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
       $type = $_GET['post_type'];
   }
   if ( 'tribe_events' == $type && $query->get( 'eventDisplay' ) == 'default') {

        $queryParamsCounter = 0;
       $notification = "2021-04-16 13:06:00";

        if (isset($notification)) {
          $meta_query['ends-after'] = array(
            'key' => '_EventEndDate',
            'value'    => $notification,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type'    => 'DATETIME',  
          );
        }
       
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);

    }
}
```

But still not working.

Does anyone know about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you post your question also here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/the-events-calendar/

Comment: I have already checked all documentation of plugin @jasie Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using parse_query.

I have modified the args of wp_query using a filter hook.

Add below code on `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'posts_filter2',15 );

function posts_filter2( $query ){
   $type = 'tribe_events';
   if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
       $type = $_GET['post_type'];
   }
   if ( 'tribe_events' == $type && $query->get( 'eventDisplay' ) == 'default') {

        $queryParamsCounter = 0;

        $format = 'Y-m-d G:i:s';
        $timezone_name = Tribe__Events__Timezones::wp_timezone_string();
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone( $timezone_name );
        $current  = date_create( '-2 hour', $timezone );
        $enddate = date_format($current,"Y-m-d G:i:s");


        if (isset($enddate)) {
          $meta_query['ends-after'] = array(
            'key' => '_EventEndDate',
            'value'    => $enddate,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type'    => 'DATETIME',  
          );
        }
       
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);

    }
}


if (isset( $meta_query['ends-after'] ) && $_GET['Recommendation'] != '')
{
  $queryParamsCounter++;
  $recommendation = $_GET['Recommendation'];
}
```

Thanks